# GC overhead error using xlsx

Tags: r, garbage-collection, rjava, r-xlsx

I am trying to read xlsx files in R using the `xlsx` library. Below is my piece of code.

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8g")
data <- read.xlsx("data.xlsx",
                  header = FALSE, sheetName="Sheet1")
```

It throws the following error

> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
>         java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

I have tried different method to increase java heap memory, but could not succeed. I am using java8 at ubuntu. The file size is 4MB only. I have followed different instructions at similar questions on different forums but could not succeed.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `read.xlsx` from the `openxlsx` library.

Comment: is it for R language?

Comment: Yes. `install.packages("openxlsx")`. It does not rely on Java, which may be useful in this case.

Comment: it is not available for R 3.2.2

Comment: Then download an older version which is supported in R 3.2.2 and compile from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [readxl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/index.html), which AFAIK is one of the most efficient ways to read Excel files in R.

Comment: hi, is there similar for writing as well?

Comment: You'll have to use `openxlsx` or something of the likes for writing unfortunately:  https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/231